# Camel RabbitMQ to REST Endpoint SpringBootTest failing

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel, integration, spring-boot-test

I'm trying to write a SpringBootTest to test a Camel route. My route looks like this:

```
 restConfiguration().producerComponent("http4")
            .host("http://127.0.0.1);

    from("rabbitmq:foo")
            .to(rest:post")
            .log("Hello!: ${body}");
```

Here's my test:

```
@RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class)
@MockEndpoints
@UseAdviceWith
@SpringBootTest
public class SimpleCamelRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {

@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:rest")
private MockEndpoint mockEndpoint;

@Autowired
CamelContext context;

@Autowired
ProducerTemplate template;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
       @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
           interceptSendToEndpoint("rabbitmq:foo")
                   .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                   .to("mock:foo");
           interceptSendToEndpoint("http://*")
                   .skipSendToOriginalEndpoint()
                   .to("mock:rest");
        }
    });
    context.start();

}


@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    String body = "Camel";
    mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

    template.sendBody("mock:foo", body);

    mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
}

}
```

It looks like it is trying to connect to a real running instance of RabbitMq on booting :(

```
18-08-2019 13:20:07.729 [Camel (camel-1) thread #3 - RabbitMQConsumer] INFO  o.a.c.c.rabbitmq.RabbitMQConsumer.call - Connection failed, will retry in 5000ms
```

java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

Can anybody offer me some advise on how to tell my SpringBootTest not to look for a running broker and to respect the mocks I have set up (assuming the mocks are set up correctly.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to intercept consumer (`from`) with `interceptSendToEndpoint`. This is not possible. For this you need [`replaceFromWith`](https://camel.apache.org/advicewith.html).

```
context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
   @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
       replaceFromWith("direct:triggerFoo");
       //...
    }
});
```

And then trigger the route like this:

```
template.sendBody("direct:triggerFoo", body);
```

---

Also you are intercepting `http4` producer, but from your route it seems you probably want to intercept `rest*` instead.